# play framework Multiple forms with checkbox fields with the same name attribute

Tags: html, forms, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a form which could have multiple smaller forms inside it. All the smaller forms have the same type of fields. I have two checkbox fields in each of the smaller forms with the `name= "timeOfTheDay"`. One checkbox has value `"morning"`. The other one has value `"evening"`. Now for all the forms the name `"timeOfTheDay"` is same, So only one value out of all the forms is getting selected. Only one selection could  be done at a time in overall form for this field.

Also I cant change the name of this field as, in Play Model, I am using the same model for all the forms, Which does mapping with name.

Please suggest some solution for this.

**My main model:**

```
public class Details {
    //Default For all customers
    public String timeOfTheDay;

    public Integer cost;

    public String day;

    //Customized details for each customers
    public CustomForm customDetails[];
}
```

**CustomForm is:**

```
public class CustomForm {
    public String timeOfTheDay;

    public Integer cost;
}
```

**defaultForm template:**

```
//these are the params i am sending while rendering the file from controllers
@(id: Long, detailsForm : Form[models.Settings.Details], isEdit: Boolean)

<div class="col-md-2 text-left min-size-label removePadding">
  <span>Day</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 removePaddingLeft">
  @input(detailsForm("day"), 'class -> "form-control col-xs-12 formField ")
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 text-left min-size-label removePadding">
  <span>Cost</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 removePaddingLeft">
  @input(detailsForm("cost"), 'class -> "form-control col-xs-12 formField ")
</div>                  

<div class="col-md-10 text-left min-size-label removePadding">
  <span><b>Time of the day</b></span>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  @inputRadioGroup(
    detailsForm("timeOfTheDay"),
    options(enums.timeOfDayEnum.timeOfDayMap()),
    'name -> "timeOfTheDay",
    'class -> "timeOfTheDay"
  )
</div>
```

**CustomForm template:**

```
@(id: Long, customDetailsForm : Form[models.Settings.CustomForm], isEdit: Boolean)

<div class="col-md-2 text-left min-size-label removePadding">
  <span>Cost</span>
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 removePaddingLeft">
  @input(customDetailsForm("cost"), 'class -> "form-control col-xs-12 formField ")
</div>

<div class="col-md-10 text-left min-size-label removePadding">
  <span><b>Time of the day</b></span>
</div>

//options are fetched from enums
<div class="col-sm-12">
  @inputRadioGroup(
    customDetailsForm("timeOfTheDay"),
    options(enums.timeOfDayEnum.timeOfDayMap()),
    'name -> "timeOfTheDay",
    'class -> "timeOfTheDay"
  )
</div>
```

Both the forms have the same timeOfTheDay named radio button field. Also I can have many customForm in a single page. Then they will obviously have the same name as they are using the same model. So how do i make selection for each of those forms individually.

Comment: You might as well publish some code.

Comment: Especially your controller code...

Comment: I have added the code @Abhi. Please help me. And do ask, if you dont understand any part.